# Faster way to Save images into internal storage

Tags: java, android, performance

My app saves some images in internal storage when the app is loading.
The problem is that the app is using the most common code for this situation, which is compressing the image before saving it, but this compressing process takes too long to be processed. For example, if there are 5 pictures to be loaded, the app take about 30 seconds to load and open the home screen. 30 seconds is too long to open an app.
My code to save the image is the following:

```
public static final boolean savePngLocalStorage(String fileName, Bitmap bitmap, Context context) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    Bitmap tmp = null;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)); //他アプリアクセス不可
        tmp = bitmap.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        return tmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
    } finally {
        if (tmp != null) {
            tmp.recycle();
            tmp = null;
        }
        //
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //IOException, NullPointerException
        }
    }
}
```

Using debug, I realized that tmp.compress command is the one that take some time to be processed.

I tried to use the following code without compressing the image. It got a bit faster.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(MainActivity.this);
File path = c.getFilesDir();
String fileName = imageIdArray[i] + ".png";
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + fileName); // "data/data/[package_name]/files/sample.png"
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

Are there other ways to save the image faster?

Comment: Use .JPG format, not PNG in  return tmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

Comment: Using .JPG format solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String path = setOutputFilePath();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            croppedBitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored

            LOGGER.debug("Saving image on the absolute path folder!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: changing the compress code to jpg (tmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos)) it got much faster! Thank you